# DynamdoDB batchget from single table with multiple object models

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm learning DynamoDB and i've a Single table design stored with various object models like Employee, Company, etc..  If i know pk & sk of a company and employee, will i be able to query two items (Item # 1 & 4) in a single call.

**Table name : APP_TABLE**

| # | pk | sk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EMP_DTL | E1 |
| 2 | EMP_DTL | E2 |
| 3 | EMP_DTL | E3 |
| 4 | CMPNY_DTL | C1 |
| 5 | CMPNY_DTL | C2 |
| 6 | CMPNY_DTL | C3 |

I tried to use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) but looks like i can't map the same table with multiple java models as shown below.

[DynamoDbEnhancedClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html).table("APP_TABLE", TableSchema.fromBean(Company.class));
DynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("APP_TABLE", TableSchema.fromBean(Employee.class));

If i use PartiQL, i'm not sure if this is valid or it would do table scan.

SELECT * FROM APP_TABLE WHERE pk IN ('EMP_DTL','CMPNY_DTL') AND sk IN ('E1','C1')";

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB Enhanced Client does not provide the functionality of a single table design, as the class is mapped directly to the table. You can either break your model into multiple tables or use a low level client that does not map your table to an object.

### Block full table Scan

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Action":[
            "dynamodb:PartiQLSelect"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/WatchList"
         ],
         "Condition":{
            "Bool":{
               "dynamodb:FullTableScan":[
                  "true"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "dynamodb:PartiQLSelect"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/WatchList"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. As suggested, i used the low level [DynamoDbClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html) and it worked fine. I've accepted the answer. BTW, Does the PartiQL in my question do table scan?

Comment: I believe it would result in multiple Query operations (4). However, to be sure it doesn't result in a full table Scan then you can block scans by IAM role. I'll add the policy to my answer.